# Previous year's winter bash pages are not redirecting to the proper site

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash, redirection, promotions

When I'm navigating to previous year's winter bash page, from Blog posts or Tag's description or directly entering the URL in browser, there is a redirect issue.

For example, Winter bash 2017 (https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com) is redirecting to its following promotion site page: https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/18/winter-bash-2017

But where as the other year's winter bash site pages are **not** navigating to its proper promotion page. It simply redirects to https://contests.stackoverflow.com/ page only.

Expected the below redirection:

```
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|              Winter Bash URL              |                     Expected Redirection To                   |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/19/winter-bash-2018 |
| https://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/17/winter-bash-2016 |
| https://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/16/winter-bash-2015 |
| https://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/15/winter-bash-2014 |
| https://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/14/winter-bash-2013 |
| https://winterbash2012.stackexchange.com  | https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/12/winter-bash-2012 |
+-------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for reporting it! A fix for this has been deployed.

As part of winterbash 2019 we've ported both the contests.stackoverflow.com and winterbash sites to ASP.NET Core. This redirect somehow slipped under our radar.

Comment: Redirection of `https://winterbash2012.stackexchange.com` is failed, it is redirecting to `https://stackexchange.com/site-not-found` page