# How does SE manage their domains and determine the ones to renew?

Tags: support, bug, redirection, domain-names, contest

Stack Exchange [owns various domains](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164054/how-many-tlds-are-currently-owned-by-stack-overflow) that were used for [various contests mini-sites across the network](https://contests.stackoverflow.com).

However, there doesn't seem to be a uniform way in which SE handles their domains. Examples below.

---

Some of these domains currently redirect to their respective contest sites, though **almost all the redirects are broken**. The SSL errors are probably broken by SE's [switch to HTTPS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time).

- http://hatdash.com [SSL error] for [HatDash is live!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3449/hatdash-is-live)
- http://thenewipadishere.com [redirect broken] for [The new iPad is here - ask different and win one!](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/the-new-ipad-is-here-ask-different-and-win-one)
- http://answerama.com [redirect broken] for [Answerama, the Futurama mini-site, is live!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1970/answerama-the-futurama-mini-site-is-live/2075)
- http://answerswarm.com [SSL error] for [AnswerSwarm](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/13/answerswarm)
- http://me3missions.com [redirect broken] for [Mass Effect 3 Missions](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/4/mass-effect-3-missions)
- http://mountainlionchallenge.com [redirect broken] for [Mountain Lion Challenge - ask, answer, blog and win Apple products!](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1365/mountain-lion-challenge-ask-answer-blog-and-win-apple-products)
- http://skyrimvsmw3.com [redirect broken] for [Skyrim vs MW3](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/1/skyrim-vs-mw3)
- http://stackshowdown.com [redirect broken] for [Avengers vs. X-Men SciFi Event!](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/avengers-vs-x-men-scifi-event)
- http://win8challenge.com [redirect broken] for [The Windows 8 Challenge has ended, thank you for blogging!](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5722/the-windows-8-challenge-has-ended-thank-you-for-blogging)

Some of these domains were not renewed and no longer owned by SE (!!!)

- http://diablo3acts.com for [Diablo 3 is coming - train with us!](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4601/diablo-3-is-coming-train-with-us)
- http://apptivate.ms for [Apptivate](https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/10/apptivate)

Some domains don't seem to have been used before but are randomly redirected to the contest main page (which is perfectly alright but I'd just want to point out).

- http://iasknyc.com
- http://vast-and-endless-sea.com

---

Of course, this list isn't exhaustive and I've missed out some.

### So,

- How does SE manage these special one-time-use event domains?
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) Can the broken redirects be pointed to the correct sites?
- How does SE decide which of these domains to renew? Did SE purposefully let the expired domains lapse or ...?

* Also related: [Previous year's winter bash pages are not redirecting to the proper site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341299/previous-years-winter-bash-pages-are-not-redirecting-to-the-proper-site).

Comment: I wonder if ssl certs would be one of the issues for these sites. The move from meta.foo.stackexchange to foo.meta.stackexchange was cause it was easier to manager the certs.

Comment: Related: Firefox now warns against [https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/](https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/): *"Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead. Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to meta.physics.stackexchange.com. The issue is most likely with the website"*

Comment: A workaround is to use `https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/` instead of `https://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/`. Perhaps it is implied, but there could be a redirect(?).